# Can a spirit have the Posture of sitting?

Tags: spirit

Scripture says God is a Spirit

It also says God sits on the throne?

Do Spirit sit on spiritual thrones?

Comment: The wording in Revelation is careful and noticeable regarding God in Spirit and God, manifest in humanity.

Comment: So by that you mean to say that God in spirit cannot sit and we can only understand his sitting viz the manifestation to humanity?

Comment: when making assumptions (like God is a spirit), please quote scriptural references for it. It might be an incorrect assumption based on incorrect interpretation, but this can't be "discussed" or answered without such reference

Comment: @fireshark519 John 4:24 _Pneuma ho Theos_ : God is (a) spirit. [TR-KJV]

Comment: @FaithMendel I wasn't answering or drawing conclusions. I was only commenting on what needs to be examined regarding a seated posture in Revelation regarding the throne : when God, in Spirit, is spoken of and when Christ, God manifest in humanity, is mentioned.

Comment: Alright @Nigel J   actually God is more captured as sitting on his throne than CHRIST (God in human manifestation) in scriptures.  So if God is Spirit and he sits in the throne ? Do Spirits sit?

Comment: God also appears to one of the Old Testament prophets while seated on a throne that was carried by angels. I think his ability to sit down shouldn’t really be in question. ;)

Comment: Am not asking if God sits.. Am saying do Spirits sit?

Answer (score 1):

We have the following facts:

- God is Spirit John 4:24
- God is seen an anthropomorphic form as seated in more than one place: Ps 110, Eze 1:26-28, Dan 7:9, Rev 4:10, Col 3:1, Luke 22:69, Mark 12:36, 14:62, Matt 20:23, 22:44, 26:62, Heb 8:1, 12:2, Eph 1;20, Acts 2:34, Rom 8:34, etc.

Whether this has any physical meaning is a completely different matter - all we do know is that is how God is often depicted, possibly in somewhat symbolic or metaphoric images, we do not know.

We know almost nothing about the physicality of spirits (eg, angels and God) so a discussion of them and their poses is almost meaningless.  The depictions in the Bible may be an accommodation to human understanding and language, so we must be careful not to make too much of this.

This is further reinforced by two facts:

1. "No man has even seen God [the Father] John 1:18
2. All the images of God [the Father] seated on a throne are in vision and surrounded by highly symbolic language (Eze 1:26-28, Dan 7:9, Rev 4:10)

Therefore, such images of God seated are almost certainly not literal.

Comment: We are made in His image. Also Daniel saw thrones Daniel 7:9 and it gives a description of what God looked like as did John when he said God looks like jasper and sardius stones. They both saw someone. Therefore God had at a minimum has an outline or form. And when you’re in the spirit the limitations of the physical is removed. Therefore trying to explain a spirit from the limits of the physical is not accurate or at least they will defy the laws that govern the physical realm. Any time angels are described they are described as (young)men. The stars or lights in the sky are said to be angels

Comment: I think we agree - explaining spiritual forms is tricky with human language.  I will include your extra reference in my list above.  Many thanks.

Comment: My question isn't actually focused on God" but Spirits generally?..  Do they attain postures, like "dwelling" if God sitting on a throne isn't to be taken literally then lots of scriptures would God down for this! Especially the coronation of our Lord.

Comment: If you want to discuss spirits generally, then the Bible has even less information about this than about God.  Even then, the only information we have about God is purely visionary material as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

> **Matthew 26:41 (KJV)**
>   Watch and pray, that ye enter not into temptation: the spirit indeed is willing, but the flesh is weak.
>
> **Luke 24:39 (KJV)**
>   Behold my hands and my feet, that it is I myself: handle me, and see; for a spirit hath not flesh and bones, as ye see me have.
>
> **John 6:63 (KJV)**
>   It is the spirit that quickeneth; the flesh profiteth nothing: the words that I speak unto you, they are spirit, and they are life.

So, according to Jesus, human beings have "flesh" (a physical form) and a "spirit" (power to animate the physical form). Adam was created a physical form into which God had to breathe His spirit in order to bring him to life (Genesis 2:7).

Does God have a physical form? Well, Paul says He does:

> **1 Timothy 3:16 (KJV)**
>   And without controversy great is the mystery of godliness: **God was manifest in the flesh**, justified in the Spirit, seen of angels, preached unto the Gentiles, believed on in the world, received up into glory.

Jesus was the first century manifestation of God in the flesh, so when Jesus sat down (Matthew 9:10, 13:1, 15:29, etc), God sat down.

Now, Jesus said:

> **John 4:24 (KJV)**
>   God is a Spirit: and they that worship him must worship him in spirit and in truth.

So, a human being cannot "worship" God with that part of its being that sits down. In order to worship God, the "spirit" of a human being must choose to move its flesh in a way that brings glory to God.

**Conclusion**
God is spirit, and as such, has no particular form, but He can manifest in whatever form suits His purposes, e.g. a pillar of cloud/fire (Exodus 13:21), a glorious form: the face of which no eye can behold (Exodus 33:20-23, 40:34-35), a man (John 1:14, 1 Timothy 3:16), a lamb with seven horns and seven eyes (Revelation 5:6), etc.

God is not sensible to human beings unless He manifests in a form that they can perceive, and when that form has what is necessary for sitting, then God can sit.

Comment: I read your response but it seems incomplete. Maybe you can elaborate further on the last two sentences please?